# How to encode a configuration file path in a Python project

Tags: python, python-2.7

Say my project has the following :

```
my_project
  /conf/conf.txt
  /lib/api
  /lib/api/common
  ...
```

Several Python scripts in different subfolders need to access `conf.txt`. What is the best practice to encode the location of `conf.txt` in my python scripts?
Absolute paths?

```
with open('/home/usualme/my_project/conf/conf.txt') as f:
  ...
```

Relative paths?

```
with open('../../conf/conf.txt') as f:
  ...
```

Something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [path module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html). And, of course, you can't use your home directory name in scripts.